# Find only youngest element in array

Tags: elasticsearch

does somebody know if there is a way to build a elasticsearch query which sorts an array by date and queries only the youngest item? To demonstrate what I mean, here is an example of my data:

```
    [{
    _id: "51cd3ae45b99bd960ee0b425",
    name: "Example entry",
    documents: [
        {
            title: "Document Title 1",
            subDocuments: [
                {
                    date: "Mon Jul 08 2013 12:14:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                    title: "start working"
                },
                {
                    date: "Fri Jul 11 2013 12:14:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                    title: "finished"
                },
                {
                    date: "Thu Jul 10 2013 12:14:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                    title: "working"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}, {
    _id: "51cd3ae45b99bd960ee0b426",
    name: "Example entry 2",
    documents: [
        {
            title: "Document Title 1",
            subDocuments: [
                {
                    date: "Mon Jul 08 2013 12:14:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                    title: "start working"
                },
                {
                    date: "Fri Jul 11 2013 12:14:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)",
                    title: "working"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

In this data I want to query for the value "working". As you can see the first document has the sub document title finished in his last status so this document is not to be allowed in the result set.

Could anybody give me a hint how to build up the query so that my requirements are met? Or is this impossible at this time and has to be developed in the client code?

Thanks and Greetings Kersten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed this with editing my data. I just copy the last status to a own property. But I think this might be the solution: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3022